# Display SQL query in a HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have some SQL query code here where if I put it into PHPMyAdmin in the correct database it displays what I want to see, but I want it to display in an HTML table, any idea?

```
SELECT  
  tname AS Team, Sum(P) AS P,Sum(W) AS W,Sum(D) AS D,Sum(L) AS L, 
  SUM(F) as F,SUM(A) AS A,SUM(GD) AS GD,SUM(Pts) AS Pts  
FROM( 
  SELECT  
    hteam Team,  
    1 P, 
    IF(hscore > ascore,1,0) W, 
    IF(hscore = ascore,1,0) D, 
    IF(hscore < ascore,1,0) L, 
    hscore F, 
    ascore A, 
    hscore-ascore GD, 
    CASE WHEN hscore > ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS 
  FROM games 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT  
    ateam, 
    1, 
    IF(hscore < ascore,1,0), 
    IF(hscore = ascore,1,0), 
    IF(hscore > ascore,1,0), 
    ascore, 
    hscore, 
    ascore-hscore GD, 
    CASE WHEN hscore < ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
  FROM games 
) as tot 
JOIN teams t ON tot.Team=t.id  
GROUP BY Team  
ORDER BY SUM(Pts) DESC ;
```

Currently when I run this code in PHPMyAdmin this is the result I get and this is what I want to output in a html table:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm trying to create this off this website:

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=804

So far I have tried to run a query but nothings coming up;

```
        <?php

    $servername = "-";
    $username = "-";
    $password = "-";
    $dbname = "-";

    // Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
} 
$query = "SELECT  
  tname AS Team, Sum(P) AS P,Sum(W) AS W,Sum(D) AS D,Sum(L) AS L, 
  SUM(F) as F,SUM(A) AS A,SUM(GD) AS GD,SUM(Pts) AS Pts  
FROM( 
  SELECT  
    hteam Team,  
    1 P, 
    IF(hscore > ascore,1,0) W, 
    IF(hscore = ascore,1,0) D, 
    IF(hscore < ascore,1,0) L, 
    hscore F, 
    ascore A, 
    hscore-ascore GD, 
    CASE WHEN hscore > ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS 
  FROM games 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT  
    ateam, 
    1, 
    IF(hscore < ascore,1,0), 
    IF(hscore = ascore,1,0), 
    IF(hscore > ascore,1,0), 
    ascore, 
    hscore, 
    ascore-hscore GD, 
    CASE WHEN hscore < ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
  FROM games 
) as tot 
JOIN teams t ON tot.Team=t.id  
GROUP BY Team  
ORDER BY SUM(Pts) DESC ; ";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    /* execute statement */
    $stmt->execute();



    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: If you show us the PHP code you have for the page you want this table on then we can help

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have edited the question and added the code, I haven't done a lot I just simply don't know where to start. The only thing is I've attached the database connection before the code.

Comment: Pro tip: we're a bit different on Stack Overflow from other sources of help on the internet. 
Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on a question prior to a question being posted.

Comment: never share credentials online forums or anywhere it is risky.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the feedback, what do you think I should do to expand. I'm not 100% sure on where to start as I am new to php and mysql I've only just started, this is my first project and I'm just not sure how I can post the output of this SQL query. I have attached the website which is what i'm trying to create.

Comment: Well I would suggest you read through the [Mysqli section of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) If once you have codes at least an attempt at a query execution and fetching the resultset if you still have issues then is when to ask a question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do something like this

```
<?php

$connection=mysqli_connect(your database parameters);
$query="sql query";
$r=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$resultset=array();  //Associative Array
echo "<div id='table'><center><table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Column Headings</th>
<tr>
</tr></center>";    
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['team'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['p'] . "</td>";
    ...
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table><br>";
?>
```